# psql --help not responding or displaying results

Tags: postgresql, psql

My `psql --help` isn't displaying anything as it should on my SQL shell for postgres. Although the tutors shell is blank and mine isn't and he didn't mention how he arrived at his being blank.

[Image from my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpCF0.png)

I tried it and it's supposed to show a couple of options per the instruction and also tried psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U sibaa test it was still unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

You are literally already inside of the psql program. As the screenshot says, just type `help` to get the result you asked for.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. I appreciate the feedback .

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted to resolve it?